# jQuery - Navbar color change on scroll works UNLESS user refreshes page halfway down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navbar

I'm trying to have a fixed navbar that is transparent at the very top of my page, and a white once the user scrolls. I have a code that ALMOST works - it's fine 90% of the time, BUT if the user refreshes the page anywhere besides at the very top, the navbar will start out transparent *at that point on the page*, rather than being white. (It does still change on scroll).

I want the navbar to always be white unless it is at the very top of the page. Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('.nav');
    var offset = startchange.offset();
     $(document).scroll(function() { 
     scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
     if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
       $('.brand-centered').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)');

   } else {
       $('.brand-centered').css('background-color', 'transparent');


   }
 });
}); 
        `
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something different like this, so in this algorithm you are gonna test 280 , if that works then you can use 100 or less

```
if (document.body.scrollTop >= 280 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 280) {
and it will work cross-browser. Cheers!

var myNav = document.getElementById("nav");

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 280 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 280) {
    myNav.classList.add("scroll");
  } else {
    myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
  }
};
```